# Over the Bridge, If You Dare

Tags: logical-deduction, story, liars, situation

A young man walks through the forest.

He comes to a bridge.

In front of the bridge is a large man carrying an axe.

The man says, "If you want to cross this bridge, you must tell me something. If I think your statement is true, I will strangle you to death. If I think your statement is false, I will chop off your head."

A few minutes later, the young man walks over the bridge, while the larger man stands pondering.

What did he say?

Comment: can i guess ? or i should post an answer

Comment: Your answer IS your guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too broad". There are *way* too many workable answers.

Comment: Please put your answer into an answer rather than in the body of the question.

Comment: Sorry; I saw that in another post and imitated it...

Comment: Maybe you should ammend it to: You must tell me a statement which I can evaluate to true or false. - Otherwise you can just ask him a question, or tell him "Beagles!" - are Beagles true or false??? - The statement should at least be required to be a true/false statement...

Comment: Flippant answer: the man with the axe is under no obligation to ensure his statement is true and he is obviously a very disturbed individual. Clearly the correct thing to do is to give him a philosophical lecture on the nature and value of life asking him to consider his life choices in just murdering people who want to cross a bridge. You need to convince him to not be a murderer...

Comment: By the exact phrasing, there is no way to guarantee safety. He doesn't say he *won't* strangle you to death if your statement is false, so he can just strangle you, and chop your head off after you're dead.

Comment: So why isn't the answer "I have a bomb on a deadman's switch"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The canonical answer:

> You will chop off my head.

But this doesn't really work because

> he can simply strangle you and then behead your corpse.

So perhaps

> You will kill me by chopping off my head.

Comment: You got it in the last guess.  I'll explain.

Comment: What if you live after he chops off your head?

Comment: @EpicGuy You can still bite him...

Comment: Haha!  "C'mon then!  I'll bite ye to death!"

Comment: He can just kill you by splitting your skull and then chop off your head after you are dead - your statement was false and he chopped off your head, so no contradiction

Answer (score 7):

How about the classic paradoxical statement:

> This statement is false.

Comment: This is what I thought when first reading the puzzle.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> "Snaaaaaa!"

Which is a statement in my made up language...

He can ponder all day if it is false or true and will never know ^^

Answer (score 2):

He said:

> if you were me what would you say?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> The young man said, "My head will be chopped off."

Explanation:

> If the axeman claimed the statement was false, the young man's head would be chopped off, making the statement true.

But if..

> But if the axeman claimed the statement was true, the young man would be strangled to death, which would make the statement false.

Summary:

> In the end, the axeman came to a bridge he could not cross. He couldn't say the young man's statement was true OR false without invalidating his question.